Specifying angle bisectors and relative position of a point.
We know that two intersecting lines include 4 angles , vertically equal in pairs, now one of those pairs might be acute or obtuse pair.
How do find which of angle bisectors  $$\frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{√a_1²+b_1²}=+-\frac{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}{√a_1²+b_1²} $$
are obtuse or acute.
I tried to use vectors but didn't get anything.
Another thing I wanted to ask is , how do I determine in which ( positive $Y$ or negative $Y$ )halfplane does a point$(\alpha,\beta)$ lie with respect to some given line , I know as much as we put $\alpha $and $\beta$ in the equation of our line and check the sign of resulting value , but what does this process represent on the graph , that is to say , what is the intuition behind this ?
Along the same lines, Does distance of a point from a line come with a sign?
Edit: if my questions are too basic , recommend me a book that has answers to my questions.

This question might help.
